# How can we know when HikariCp has fully initialized its pool?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I want to start my service after HikariCP has added all connection to its pool. I am using Spring Boot.

I have a large Pool size, but while starting the application it takes a lot of time for HikariCP to add the connections and I get Connection timeouts.

Comment: Post your configuration

Answer (score 5):

It is undocumented (and therefore officially unsupported), but you can set the Java system property `com.zaxxer.hikari.blockUntilFilled=true`.